Automatic Keying not inserting keys for for all transforms
Currently working in Blender 4.1.1
Maybe I am misremembering something, but usually when I animate and move or rotate bones in Pose Mode Blender will set keyframes for all X,Y,Z transforms. If I move a bone along the Y axis in my viewport I still want it to key all other location axes but it is only keying the Y this is not the behavior I'm used to. I opened an older file with a character and the auto keying is doing what I expect.
I can't seem to find anything in the "preferences" or "key" menus that helps.

In Preferences > Animation, uncheck Only Insert Needed for Manual/Auto

Thanks this does kind of help, I guess what I was looking for doesn't really exist. I was hoping for the behavior to be more like move location of bone on Y axis in viewport and it auto keys all axes related to location as opposed to all transforms.

@It'sJustChris see if you can combine that preference setting with a Keying set (only location for example)
